# Strategy not returning any data

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5

I am running into some issues when defining the quantity type and values for the below strategy. For some reason, after I add these parameters I am not retrieving any data when i know this strategy should be trading in the time period I have it set-up.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Trend Following Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = 1, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 10, initial_capital = 1000 )


//input variables
stop_lookback = input.int(150, "Stop Look-back")
sma_period = input.int(200, "SMA Period")
trend_filter_lookback = input.int(500, "Trend Filter Look-back")
ATR_buffer = input.int(14, "ATR buffer")

//Trend Filter Variables
ma_slow = ta.ema (close, sma_period) // moving average
ma_fast = ta.ema (close, 50) // moving average
ma_prev_high= ta.highest(ma_slow, trend_filter_lookback) //Previous high of the EMA
trending_Market = ma_slow >= ma_prev_high//Current ma value is greater than previous ma value

//Trigger Condition
[macdLine, macdSig, macdHist ] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9) // get MACD indicator
trigger = ma_fast > ma_slow and close > ma_slow and macdLine < 0 and macdSig <0 and macdLine > macdSig and macdHist[1] > 0 and macdHist[2] > 0

//Stop Loss Variables
prev_lows = ta.lowest(low, stop_lookback) //Price action Low
atr = ta.atr(ATR_buffer) //Average True Range - Stop Loss Buffer
price_stop = 0.0 //Stop initially set as null

//Long Condition
longCondition = trending_Market and trigger //go long if market is trending and trigger is hit
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

//Once in the position declare the below variables
if (strategy.position_size> 0)
   
// Stop Loss Computation
    stopValue = prev_lows - atr //Stop loss value including ATR buffer
    price_stop := math.max(stopValue, price_stop[1] ) //Trailing condition for SL
   
else 
    price_stop := 0 // If no position set SL to null

//exit condition   
if (strategy.position_size>0) //apply the exit strategy with variables declared upon entry
    strategy.exit(id= "Stop Loss", stop= price_stop  )
```

Comment: I've done some trouble shooting from my end and the issue seems to be with the following function -  strategy(title="Trend Following Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = 1, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 1000, initial_capital = 100000). Is there any reason why once I set the parameters on the strategy function the strategy does not return any trades?

Comment: What's the tickerid and timeframe you are testing this on?

Comment: the ticker is SPX and timeframe is the 1hr .... but this should be set as default when im viewing the chart, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't have enough cash.

Your initial capital is set to $1000. If I apply your strategy to SP:SPX on 1h timeframe, the first entry is a long one on 11 Sep 2014. The price is around $1990 there. And Tradingview wants you to have at least 1 contract.

So, increase your initial capital to $10000 and enter the trade with 100% of your equity and you will see that there are trades.

[image]